# Node process not terminating when using superagent cache plugin

Tags: typescript, caching, superagent

Im currently using this plugin in a typescript project which is run on AWS lambda or within lambda docker container (SAM Tool) locally. When I activate the cache plugin the lambda functions do not terminate anymore.

I also tried the superagent call via mocha testing framework. In this case the process does not terminate either, although all testing output is written to the console.

Furthermore it seems as if something worked fine. The items are written to the redis instance, but the lambda functions do not terminate.

These are the installed versions

```
├── typescript@3.3.4000
├── superagent@4.1.0
├── superagent-cache-plugin@2.0.1
├── cache-service-redis@2.0.0
```

I needed to declare modules for them as there are no typings available. Im no typescript expert. So maybe the error is located here.

```
# cache-service-redis.ts
declare module 'cache-service-redis';
```

```
# superagent-cache-plugin.ts
declare module 'superagent-cache-plugin';
```

This is the setup

```
import RedisCache = require('cache-service-redis');
import superagentCache = require('superagent-cache-plugin');
...
const redisConfig = {
    defaultExpiration: 300,
    redisData: {
        hostname: process.env.CacheEndpoint,
        port: 6379,
    },
    type: 'app',
};
const redisCache = new RedisCache(redisConfig);
const cache = superagentCache(redisCache);
const request = superagent.get('...').use(cache)
const response = await request
```

Thanks in advance. I'd really like to solve this issue and use the package. I will happily provide more information when needed  =)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the help of the maintainer by setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` after I read [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hassy/eaea5a958067211f2fed02ead13c2678) which shows a minimal example of the problem.

Any ongoing discussion about this can be found [within the issue at github](https://github.com/jpodwys/superagent-cache-plugin/issues/9).